# Can't target multiple iframes by width in Watir

Tags: iframe, watir

```
require 'watir'

@browser = Watir::Browser.new #:phantomjs (same for firefox)
@browser.window.maximize 

@browser.goto 'http://www.romnation.net/'

a = @browser.iframes(width: '160')
puts a[0].width
```

Which returns **728**. Even though I explicitly stated that I only want iframes of width **160**.

```
a = @browser.iframe(width: '160')
puts a.width
```

This returns **160**, as expected.

Why is that, how do I target multiple iframes of certain  width? (except for checking every iframe for its width)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in `IFrameCollection#to_a`

`IFrameCollection#elements` is collecting the proper subset of iframes, but using the index number of the subset on the overall list of iframes it finds on the page. I'll spend some time on it this weekend. When I make a pull request I'll link it here.

In the meantime, this "works" but isn't ideal because it gives you an Element and not an IFrame:

`iframes = browser.elements(css: "iframe[width='160']")`
`iframes.first.attribute_value('width') => 160`